# std::list.unique() should invalidate iterators?

Tags: c++

I have this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>

int main()
{    
    typedef std::list<int> list;
    int i0t[5]={-1, 2, 3, 3, 5};
    list list_1(i0t, i0t+5);
    list::reverse_iterator ri0 = ++list_1.rbegin();    
    list_1.unique();
    list_1.remove(3);
    int val = *ri0; // why is this valid ?
    std::cout << "val = " << val << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

My intuition was that ri0 iterator would become invalid after
list_1.unique();
list_1.remove(3);
using MS VS2005 Debug configuration with _HAS_ITERATOR_DEBUGGING=1
However, I think "iterator debugging" didn't catch this. Right ?

Thank you.

Comment: Perhaps try `ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL=3`?

Comment: @Andy MSDN shows an [_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh697468.aspx) of 2 as maximum. Is there an undocumented 3 setting?

Comment: @Praetorian: You're right, I made some confusion. Sorry about that, I meant level 2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> My intuition was that ri0 iterator would become invalid

Yes, it would. Per § 23.3.5.5

> void remove(const T& value)
>
> void unique()
>
> [...] Invalidates only the iterators and references to the erased
>   elements.

So, behavior of your program is undefined.

Comment: Yes, this is what the Standard says, but the OP is asking about a MS-specific behavior that does not seem to work as documented

Comment: @AndyProwl, I haven't MSVS, so, I can't explain its behavior. But I answered for the question in the title: "std::list.unique() should invalidate iterators?".

Answer (score 1):

23.3.5.5/15 states that the effects of a remove operation performed on a list will only invalidate iterators and references to erased elements. It does not specify that the operation *must* invalidate those iterators. The iterator remaining valid is *unspecified* behavior and is not guaranteed to occur in other implementations. *Accessing* the iterator after the modification however is undefined behavior.

Comment: His iterator is pointing at element `3`, which he then removes from the list. MSVC's iterator debugging is somehow not catching this.

Comment: @Praetorian Thanks. I missed that so I went back and re-read the sections on list and updated my answer.